# mercurial: any command or python api to get repository name

Tags: mercurial

Is there any Mercurial command or Python API that could yield the repo name? This will help developing cross-repo scripts.

The only related solution that I found is to parse the `.hg/hgrc [paths]` section 'default' config option.

```
[paths]
default = ssh://server//path/tools
```

There must be a more elegant solution, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no real concept of a "repository name" in Mercurial (a repository doesn't "know" or care about its own name). I think you mean "last past component of the default pull path"?

If so, then parsing the output of `hg path default` would be the most direct way to get that information.

However, you should note that the default path can (and often is) changed: think of cloning a local clone time for testing:

```
$ hg clone http://server/lib-foo
$ hg clone lib-foo lib-foo-test
$ hg clone lib-foo-test lib-foo-more-testing
```

The `lib-foo-more-testing` clone has a default push path back to `lib-foo-test`.

This means that parsing `hg paths default` wont be much more reliable than using `basename $(hg root)` — both can be completely different from the (base)name of the repository that was originally cloned.

If what you really want is to get an "identity" for a repository, then you should instead use

```
$ hg log -r 0 --template "{node}"
```

The first changeset hash in a repository will normally uniquely identify the repository and it will be stable even when clones change names. (If a repository has two or more roots, then the zeroth changeset can in principle differ between clones. People will have to actively try to make it differ, though.)

Comment: This explains why it seems so basic but no obvious solution that I can found. Thanks! Super answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get last segment of path for remote `default` alias, processing output of `hg path default` will be better choice

If you want to get **local directory name** of you mercurial repository, I haven't good solution, except checking code of Notify extension (in which, after some tricks, [you can get project-name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17461824/960558))

Comment: You can use the `hg root` command to return the local directory name, and use `basename` to extract the last component. So if your project is in `/Users/jrh/code/halo7`, this would yield `halo7`.

Comment: hg root returns local path/dir, which could be completely different from the repo name.

Comment: @gavinb - what about Winboys, which haven't basename on the board?

Comment: @frankc As Martin points out above, there is no canonical definition of a unique repo name per se; it is only by convention and is usually the repo name.

Comment: @LazyBadger You can always install CygWin to get a complete suite *nix of command-line tools on Windows. Otherwise, you might be able to use some of the %~ features in DOS shell (see http://www.computerhope.com/forhlp.htm).

Comment: @gavinb - say it admin in the Corporate Network, ok?! Forget about home-users, think about business-environment

Comment: @LazyBadger Nothing in the question (or the phrase "Winboys") implies the context was only for Corporate Networks. Also, Plenty of non-home users use Cygwin. Anyway, as per the reference I posted, you can use the command: "echo %~n1" to extract the base name of the path parameter passed.