# Mercurial repository URL equivalent of SVN info

Tags: version-control, mercurial

If I do `hg clone <MY_URL> <MY_DIR>` then `cd MY_DIR`, I want a command to retrieve 'MY_URL'. In SVN there was an easy `svn info` command which would give me the whole URL (among other things), which is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
$ hg paths default
```

to get the default pull URL, that is, the URL that will be used if you run `hg pull`.

*Note:* This URL can be changed by the user (by editing `.hg/hgrc`). The URL wont always point back to the server where the repository came from:

```
$ hg clone http://company/repos/project
$ hg clone project project2
```

Inside the `project2` clone, the default path will be `../project`. Please see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17501559/110204) if you're trying to use the default path to determine the "identity" of a repository.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer... `hg paths`

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain a little further, for the sake of future visitors...