# mercurial: how do I get the project's root folder name in changegroup hook?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

I'm aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497455/mercurial-any-command-or-python-api-to-get-repository-name) and maybe there is no solution to my problem in the end anyway. However, what I want to achieve is this:

Whenever a changeset for a repo on my server is incoming, I want to perform some custom tasks. I added a `hooks` section to `hgweb.config`:

```
[hooks]
changegroup = printenv > /tmp/test/env.txt
```

From the info that `printenv` gives me I see that I'm able to extract my unique identifier for the repo, but not the name of project! I do need the name of the repo's root folder for an API call. Is there any way I can get this information?

Comment: External hooks should be executed with the repository's root as the working directory. You can get that via `"$PWD"` or `"$(pwd)"` in a shell script. For the last part of the folder, use `"$(basename $PWD)"` or `"$(basename "$(pwd)")"`.

Comment: What I said, when I look at the output of ``printenv`` I see the content of ``"$PWD"`` but the basename is the unique identifier not the name of the project as it was initially created.

Comment: Mercurial projects do not have a name and it is not stored anywhere, except as the directory name (or part of it) as a matter of convention. If you store a repository in a differently named directory, you lose that information.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I thought the server-side directory name was some unique hash created by mercurial. But in my case it is created by the ``django`` app that exposes the repos via an UI. If you put your first comment into an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2):

`hg root` gives you the directory the repository resides in.

However there is no "unique name" or anything like that - it's simply the name of the directory and it can be changed by a simple rename command on file system level.